# Doing a Word Search for C++ and its not outputting where the word is just the first letter of the word

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, wordsearch

This is what I have to look for the word & is repeated exactly the same for other directions (N,S,etc) inside the for loop (i didnt include it bc of length) except I have rowBlock and colBlock +run or -run:

```
for (int rowBlock = 0; rowBlock < 18; rowBlock++) {
    for (int colBlock = 0; colBlock < 18; colBlock++) {
        if (string(1, namesToSearch[i][0]) == (wordSearchBlock[rowBlock][colBlock])) {
            PsblRow = rowBlock;
            PsblCol = colBlock;
            //checking in the NW direction
            for (int run = 1; run <= namesToSearch[i].length(); run++) {
                if (string(1, namesToSearch[i][1]) == (wordSearchBlock[rowBlock - run][colBlock - run]) && (rowBlock - run) >= 0 && (colBlock - run) >= 0) {
                    direction = "NW";
                    if (run = namesToSearch[i].length()) {
                        cout << movieName << " found at " << PsblRow << ", " << PsblCol << ": (direction = " << direction << ")" << endl;
                        wordExists++;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

To give some context: namesToSearch is a vector of strings & wordSearchBlock is an array[18][18]
PLEASE HELP ME!! I dont know whats wrong this is an example of the output I keep getting:

```
ALL OF ME found at 2, 9: (direction = NE)
ALL OF ME found at 2, 17: (direction = N)
ALL OF ME found at 2, 17: (direction = N)
ALL OF ME found at 2, 17: (direction = SE)
ALL OF ME found at 5, 3: (direction = SE)
ALL OF ME found at 5, 3: (direction = SE)
ALL OF ME found at 5, 6: (direction = S)
ALL OF ME found at 5, 6: (direction = S)
ALL OF ME found at 5, 12: (direction = W)
ALL OF ME found at 5, 12: (direction = W)
ALL OF ME found at 5, 12: (direction = SE)
ALL OF ME found at 5, 12: (direction = SE)
ALL OF ME found at 6, 0: (direction = N)
ALL OF ME found at 6, 0: (direction = N)
ALL OF ME found at 6, 0: (direction = SE)
ALL OF ME found at 7, 7: (direction = NW)
ALL OF ME found at 7, 7: (direction = W)
ALL OF ME found at 7, 7: (direction = W)
ALL OF ME found at 8, 0: (direction = NE)
ALL OF ME found at 8, 4: (direction = NE)
ALL OF ME found at 8, 4: (direction = NE)
ALL OF ME found at 8, 4: (direction = E)
ALL OF ME found at 8, 17: (direction = SE)
ALL OF ME found at 9, 9: (direction = SW)
ALL OF ME found at 9, 9: (direction = S)
ALL OF ME found at 10, 14: (direction = NE)
ALL OF ME found at 10, 17: (direction = NE)
ALL OF ME found at 10, 17: (direction = W)
ALL OF ME found at 11, 11: (direction = W)
ALL OF ME found at 11, 11: (direction = E)
ALL OF ME found at 11, 11: (direction = SW)
ALL OF ME found at 11, 15: (direction = NE)
ALL OF ME found at 11, 16: (direction = N)
ALL OF ME found at 12, 11: (direction = NW)
ALL OF ME found at 12, 11: (direction = NE)
ALL OF ME found at 12, 11: (direction = W)
ALL OF ME found at 12, 13: (direction = NW)
ALL OF ME found at 13, 17: (direction = NE)
ALL OF ME found at 15, 14: (direction = S)
ALL OF ME found at 15, 15: (direction = SW)
ALL OF ME found at 15, 15: (direction = SW)
```

And the real location is at 8,4.

Comment: Unclear to understand the code and the issue. Please edit the question and make sure that the question is clear to understand. First include the task you are trying to do and what issue do you face (which part of task did you get stuck in). Then, include a [mre] - code which one can copy-paste, run and reproduce the issue. Then, include sample inputs if any and expected output.

Comment: Please indent your code properly.